# Need to use $scope.apply() otherwise view sometimes slow

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

So i'm building a web application in AngularJS that connects to an API (Qlik Sense Engine API) with QSocks.

Qsocks is a lightweight wrapper around the Qlik Sense Engine API wrapper that is written in NodeJS but can also be imported in a web environment. QSocks contains and uses the NPM package Promise package so it uses it's own non AngularJS promises.

My service looks like this:

```
var app_promise = (appFactory.activeConnection() ? appFactory.activeConnection() : appFactory.app());

    this.getData = function(qMeasures, time) {

        ratioChild.qHyperCubeDef.qMeasures[0].qDef.qDef = qMeasures;
        ratioChild.qHyperCubeDef.qMeasures[0].qDef.qLabel = qMeasures;

        ratioChild.qHyperCubeDef.qDimensions[4].qDef.qFieldDefs = [time];
        ratioChild.qHyperCubeDef.qDimensions[4].qDef.qFieldLabels = [time];

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        app_promise.then(function (obj) {
            obj.createChild(ratioChild).then(function (childObj) {
                deferred.resolve(childObj);
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;

    }
```

In simple words, when i call this service in e.g. a controller. I get an object where i can build other objects on it.

**Side Note:**
I do need to make a new AngularJS promise because `app_promise.then` and `obj.createChild(ratioChild).then` are the NPM promise package promises.

This is how my controller looks like (first part):

```
        if (!$rootScope.balanceSheetFixedObj) {

            var fixYearsqMeasure = "Sum({<Jaar=>}Saldo)";
            balanceSheetService.getData(fixYearsqMeasure, self.time).then(function (childObj) {

                $rootScope.balanceSheetFixedObj = childObj;
                return childObj;

            }).then(handleFixData)
        } else {
            handleFixData();
        }
```

This is how my controller looks like (second part):

```
        function handleFixData(childObj) {

            childObj = (childObj) ? childObj : $rootScope.balanceSheetFixedObj;

            childObj.getLayout().then(function(data) {

                self.data = data;

                if (data.qHyperCube.qPivotDataPages[0].qData.length > 0) {

                    var fixPivotData = data.qHyperCube.qPivotDataPages[0];

                    self.labels = fixPivotData.qLeft;
                    $scope.$apply(); // Here is my problem!
```

With `$scope.$apply()` my view is publishes/updated after a second.

If i leave out the `$scope.$apply()` it do publish/update the view but after 10-15 Seconds.. Way to late! Why is my view so slow? I would like to leave out the `$scope.$apply()`

Comment: Try to replace `deferred.resolve(childObj);` with `$scope.$apply(function() {deferred.resolve(childObj);})`. This way a digest cycle is triggered when the "non-angular" promise resolves and the view will get updated properly.

Comment: @floribon `$scope` doesn't exist in service

Comment: Does `childObj.getLayout()` return  a `QSocks` promise? Service shown should take care of `$apply` by using `$q` as you are doing

Comment: @charlietfl sorry I mean $rootScope, you can get it from your service function `function($rootScope)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve my own problem. After looking back it was quite obvious what my problem was.

Thanks to **@charlietfl** i've taken a look to the `childObj.getLayout()`. What i saw what that the `getLayout()` function returns a QSocks promise and the code that updates my view was written inside of the `.then()` of the QSocks promise. As `getLayout()` is not an angular promise, this was the problem. My view was not updated properly.

My solution was to create a service function that creates an Angular Promise

```
    this.getObjLayout = function(childObj) {

        var deferred = $q.defer();
        childObj.getLayout().then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

And in the controller i invoke that function

```
        function handleFixData(childObj) {

            childObj = (childObj) ? childObj : $rootScope.balanceSheetFixedObj;

            balanceSheetService.getObjLayout(childObj).then(function (data) {

                self.data = data;

                if (data.qHyperCube.qPivotDataPages[0].qData.length > 0) {

                    var fixPivotData = data.qHyperCube.qPivotDataPages[0];
                    self.labels = fixPivotData.qLeft;
                }
            })
        }
```